# How to extract all zip files in subfolders in same folder using powershell and delete original zip files

Tags: powershell

I have a nested folder structure for example like this (it's a lot more for simplicity I put an example)

```
 - folder1
    - folderA
       a.zip
    - folderB
       b.zip
```

I want to unzip all zip files in same folder and delete the original zip file.

so my expected output is like

```
 - folder1
    - folderA
       - a
         files in a.zip
    - folderB
       - b
         files in b.zip
```

I can get list of all zip files by  `Get-ChildItem '.' -R -Filter *.zip` command
Then also I can pipe it to unzip like

```
Get-ChildItem '.' -R -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -Force -DestinationPath c:\a
```

which giving a fixed destination path
Also I can able to get the folder name of each zip file by

```
 Get-ChildItem '.' -R -Filter *.zip | select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName
```

also I tried

```
Get-ChildItem '.' -R -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -Force -DestinationPath $_.DirectoryName

and

Get-ChildItem '.' -R -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -Force -DestinationPath %{$_.DirectoryName}

also 
Get-ChildItem '.' -R -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -Force -DestinationPath {$_.DirectoryName}
```

But I can't find a way to pass the DirectoryName to Expand-Archive command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in case someone else has same issue

```
Get-ChildItem '.' -R -Filter *.zip | ForEach-Object {
     Expand-Archive $_.FullName "$($_.DirectoryName)/$($_.Basename)" -Force
     # Remove-Item $_.FullName # this line is removing the original zip file, commenting out in case someone copy-paste
}
```

Comment: Heads up for anyone who stumbles on this answer without reading all the details of the question or looking too carefully at the code, that this will delete all the original zip files after unzipping. This is what the OP wanted, but not immediately apparent from the title of the question alone.

Comment: @Austin Thanks for your note, commenting the remove line

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `Directory` property of the `FileInfo` objects outputted by `Get-ChildItem` to get the `DirectoryInfo` object of the parent folder of these files, then you can call the `FullName` property of the parents to get the destination folder.

In theory, this could work using `-PipelineVariable` instead of a `ForEach-Object` loop but I haven't personally tested it.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Get-ChildItem '.' -R -Filter *.zip | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $_.FullName -DestinationPath $_.Directory.FullName -Force
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: @Reza thank you, I think it was worth showing a maybe more OO approach